# Why is a class __dict__ a mappingproxy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary, python-internals

I wonder why a class `__dict__` is a `mappingproxy`, but an instance `__dict__` is just a plain `dict`

```
>>> class A:
...     pass

>>> a = A()
>>> type(a.__dict__)
<class 'dict'>
>>> type(A.__dict__)
<class 'mappingproxy'>
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

This helps the interpreter assure that the keys for class-level attributes and methods can only be strings.

Elsewhere, Python is a "consenting adults language", meaning that dicts for objects are exposed and mutable by the user.  However, in the case of class-level attributes and methods for classes, if we can guarantee that the keys are strings, we can simplify and speed-up the common case code for attribute and method lookup at the class-level.  In particular, the __mro__ search logic for new-style classes is simplified and sped-up by assuming the class dict keys are strings.

Comment: And for the curious: `mappingproxy` makes `class.__dict__` read-only, so that only `class.__setattr__` remains as an avenue for setting class attributes, and it is that method that [enforces the restriction](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ed694938c61a/Objects/object.c#l1132).

Comment: This is also relevant for anyone overriding `type.__setattr__` (which is hopefully/probably a pretty small set), since you can't write to `__dict__`; you have to use `super()`.

Comment: It also makes sure that if you give a class a new magic method, Python can update the relevant C-level slot. If you bypass this by using something like `gc.get_referents(FooClass.__dict__)[0]['__eq__'] = eqmethod`, instances of `FooClass` might not actually use `eqmethod` for `==` comparisons.

Comment: I guess anyone wanting to serialise a derived class into Json is just unlucky then :/

Comment: @MartijnPieters To clarify, this read-only nature is the reason why class attributes can only be re-assigned via access through the class itself? And why an attempt to re-assign a class attribute via access through an instance results in a new instance attribute of the same name as the class attribute?

Comment: @soporific312: yes to the first, no to the second. Assignment to attribute names on an instance is handled by `type(instance).__setattr__(instance, name, value)` anyway, never through more direct routes, and has nothing to do with the read-only nature of the class `__dict__` attribute.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I may understand instance attribute assignment better now if I am interpreting the implications of your comment correctly. If I have a class with class attribute "foo" and instance attribute of "bar" and I made the assignment "class_instance.foo = 3", the class dict is not even accessed because the compiler knows ahead of time that this is an assignment on an instance? Still, Beazley & Jones' use of descriptor class attributes (https://github.com/dabeaz/python-cookbook/blob/master/src/8/creating_a_new_kind_of_class_or_instance_attribute/example1.py) allows instance assignment?

Comment: @soporific312: comments are really not the place to discuss this; instance attribute assignment always goes through the class `__setattr__` method, which makes all the decisions as to where the value is to be stored.

Comment: I'm trying to replace a class `__members__` mapping proxy with a new one, but the `__members__` attribute is also read only. I wonder if there's a way ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75587442/validate-pydantic-dynamic-float-enum-by-name-with-openapi-description

Answer (score 23):

A mappingproxy is simply a dict with no `__setattr__` method.

You can check out and refer to this code.

```
from types import MappingProxyType
d={'key': "value"}
m = MappingProxyType(d)
print(type(m)) # <class 'mappingproxy'>

m['key']='new' #TypeError: 'mappingproxy' object does not support item assignment
```

---

mappingproxy is since Python 3.3. The following code shows dict types:

```
class C:pass
ci=C()
print(type(C.__dict__)) #<class 'mappingproxy'>
print(type(ci.__dict__)) #<class 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 19):

Since Python 3.3 `mappingproxy` type was [renamed](https://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html#types) from `dictproxy`. There was an interesting [discussion](https://bugs.python.org/issue14386) on this topic.

It's a little bit hard to find the documentation for this type, but the documentation for [vars](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#vars) method describes this perfectly (though it [wasn't documented](https://bugs.python.org/issue26547) for a while):

> Objects such as modules and instances have an updateable `__dict__`
> attribute; however, other objects may have write restrictions on their
> `__dict__` attributes (for example, classes use a types.MappingProxyType to prevent direct dictionary updates).

If you need to [assign](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432786/how-to-assign-a-new-class-attribute-via-dict) a new class attribute you could use `setattr`. It worth to note that `mappingproxy` is not JSON serializable, check out the [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue34858) to understand why.

---

Also the history of this type is a quite interesting:

- **Python 2.7:** `type(A.__dict__)` returns `<type 'dict'>` as `type(dict())`, and it's possible to assign new attributes through `__dict__`, e.g. `A.__dict__['foo'] = 'bar'`.
- **Python 3.0 - 3.2:** `type(A.__dict__)` returns `<class 'dict_proxy'>`, the difference is introduced. Trying to assign a new attribte gives `TypeError`. There was an [attempt](https://bugs.python.org/issue14386) to add `dictproxy` as a public built-in type.
- **Python 3.3:** adds the `<class 'mappingproxy'>` type described above.