# How do I define a postfix function in Python?

Tags: python, function, postfix-notation

I know that if you create your own object you can define your own methods on that object.

`my_object_instance.mymethod()`

I also know you can define infix functions with the [infix](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/infix/) package.

`obj1 |func| obj2`

What I want is the ability to define a function which accepts an existing type in postfix notation.

For example given a list `l` we may want to check if it is sorted. Defining a typical function might give us

```
if is_sorted(l): #dosomething
```

but it might be more idiomatic if one could write

```
if l.is_sorted(): #dosomething
```

Is this possible without creating a custom type?

Comment: if what you want is a function that accepts a type as an argument, then you don't need to do anything; types are first class objects in python

Comment: Postfix notation is something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is inheritance, creating a custom type by inheriting `list` and adding the new functionality.  Monkeypatching is not a strength of Python.  But since you specifically asked:

> Is this possible without creating a custom type?

What [kindall mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42965291/674039) stands, Python does not allow it.  But since nothing in the implementation is truly read-only, you can approximate the result by hacking in the class dict.

```
>>> def is_sorted(my_list):
...     return sorted(my_list) == my_list
... 
>>> import gc
>>> gc.get_referents(list.__dict__)[0]['is_sorted'] = is_sorted
>>> [1,2,3].is_sorted()
True
>>> [1,3,2].is_sorted()
False
```

The new "method" will appear in `vars(list)`, the name will be there in `dir([])`, and it will also be available/usable on instances which were created *before* the monkeypatch was applied.

This approach uses the [garbage collector interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) to obtain, via the class [`mappingproxy`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32720492/674039), a reference to the underlying dict.  And garbage collection by reference counting is a CPython implementation detail.  Suffice it to say, this is dangerous/fragile and you should not use it in any serious code.

If you like this kind of feature, you might enjoy [<kbd>ruby</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) as a programming language.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect

Answer (score 0):

Python does not generally allow monkey-patching of built-in types because the common built-in types aren't written in Python (but rather C) and do not allow the class dictionary to be modified. You have to subclass them to add methods as you want to.