# Python 3.4 caused type function error

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am a fresher in python.I had python 2.7 and 3.4.When I compile python 3.4 I get the following error but not in 2.7

```
File "C:\pyprojects\focus\site\focus2\flow.py", line 24, in _wrapper
    cls._meta = type("Meta", (), BaseFlowTile.Meta.__dict__)
TypeError: type() argument 3 must be dict, not mappingproxy
```

If I just use dict instead `__dict__` then I get the following error

```
AttributeError: type object 'Meta' has no attribute 'dict'
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Very sorry , i read it the wrong way!

Comment: I have changed the title and the post too.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.3 introduced a [MappingProxyType](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MappingProxyType), that basically allowed some [optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32720603/429982).

You should be able to use a copy of this for both Python versions:

```
cls._meta = type("Meta", (), BaseFlowTile.Meta.__dict__.copy())
```

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra:  It did take a bit to track down - it's always a pleasure to come across an interesting (uncommon) question like yours.