# Is type(name, bases, dict) could be used to create instance(object of class), for example inside Singleton

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

So there is `object.__new__(cls)` and `super().__new__(cls)` functions could be used to create instance, but could I use `type(name, bases, dict)(*args, **kwargs)` to create instance?

```
class Singleton(object):

  instance = None

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

  def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(cls.instance, type(None)):
      mcls = cls.__class__
      cls.instance = type(mcls.__name__, mcls.__bases__, dict(cls.__dict__))(*args, *kwargs)

    return cls.instance

s = Singleton()
print(s)
```

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: experimenting  :)

Comment: well, the error is pretty explicit, you are passing a `mappingproxy` instead of a `dict`, to argument 3, so do `dict(mcls.__dict__)`. Note, there's another error that I'm trying to figure out there...

Comment: Thanks, i had change to dict(mcls.__dict__) in result:  TypeError: type __qualname__ must be a str, not getset_descriptor

Comment: Yeah, so, what's going on there is that `type` has a descriptor for `__qualname__`. It expects a `str` apparently.

Comment: You should simplify this: you are trying to create a *metaclass* using `type`. This complicates things, and I'll admit, has my head scratching a bit.

Comment: also i had found that dict(cls.__dict__) is cause no errors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720492/why-is-a-class-dict-a-mappingproxy    but there come some maximum recursion error ))

Comment: So, I would suggest re-writing your question and removing the unecessary context of being in a `__new__` implementation. What you are asking is why doesn't `type(type.__name__, type.__bases__, dict(type.__dict__))` work

Comment: So, when I define a metaclass explicitly, e.g. `class Meta(type): pass`, then `Meta.__dict__` returns `mappingproxy({'__doc__': None, '__module__': '__main__'})`

Comment: But again, **why** are you trying to create a metaclass that mimics `type` in all but ... identity? And yes, that may cause no errors, but neither would `{}`.

Comment: hmm with type(arg1,arg2,arg3) i can create any class right? so if i can create class i can create instance of it. I only wanted to be sure that there is no other ways to create instance of class then object.__new__(cls), super().__new__(cls).

Comment: What? Can you elaborate in the question itself?

Comment: Sorry, added more description to question.

Comment: You *can* do this, but then, `isinstance(s, Singleton)` would be *`False`*. Why do you want to do this??? Why are you trying to use the attributes from `type`, ie. `mcls`????

Comment: I had see something like this in django source code for models, so trying to understand it on less complicated example

Comment: But **why** are you using `mclas`? You realize `mclas is type`, right?

Comment: Without cls.__class__.__bases__ i can't use type to add superclasses to instance. Also in result of type(a1,a2,a3) i think that i have callable class, if i call it i will have instance or am i wrong? Also can you post answer i will mark it and close question.

Comment: What do you mean? why are you using `cls.__class__.__bases__`, why not `(object,)`?

Comment: Youw ill have an instance, but note, this means your singleton instance, s, will have the property that `isinstance(s, Singleton) is False`

Comment: Becouse it's singleton and i want that instance has all class attributes, fields. methods ... etc including inheritence

Comment: Then you want to use `cls` , not the metaclass. Again that is *`type`*...

Comment: Yes i know that isinstance will return false

Comment: hmm are you sure about using cls and not cls.__class__ ? try this: '__bases__' in dir(cls) and '__bases__' in dir(cls.__class__)

Comment: yes, so what? What is your point?? That's the `__bases__` descriptor. Do you understand what `cls.__class__` is??

Comment: Can you post example how to create instance using type, please?

Comment: `type('MyClass',(),{})()`

Comment: Note, btw, that `Singleton.__bases__` gives `(object,)`, so you **can** use `cls` and not `cls.__clas__`, which **doesn't make sense to begin with**. Why are you using the *metaclass* attributes to create an instance of the class? The *class* creates instances of the class, the metaclass creates the *class*

Comment: I had posted complete example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i couldn't find the way to keep `__new__` method in `cls.__dict__` it leads to recoursion so i removed it before class creation.

```
class FooMixin(object):
  def print_somth(self):
    print('smth....')


class Singleton(FooMixin):

  instance = None

  def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if cls.instance is None:
      temp = dict(cls.__dict__)
      del temp['__new__']
      temp['test'] = 100
      cls.instance = type('Singleton', cls.__bases__, temp)(*args, **kwargs)
    return cls.instance

s = Singleton()
print(s.test, s.print_somth())
```

Comment: To deal with the recursion error, just remove `__new__` from the `dict` you pass as the third argument.

Comment: You realize, btw, that `__call__` is never actually being *called*, right? I.e., nothing you wrote in `__call__` is doing anything...

Comment: This is not a singleton, it's a singleton factory.

Comment: @Rawing well, it's not even that. `Singleton.instance` is always `None`.

Comment: Why are you using `cls.__class__.__bases__`? Why not just `type.__bases__`, or `cls.__bases__`?

Comment: Becouse cls hasn't __bases__ field, only cls.__class__ has. Ah okey it has it but dir(cls) doesn't contain it realy nice....

Comment: Also, there are a few other odd choices in your code. Why waste a method call doing  `'self'.upper()` instead of `'SELF'`? Why put a `pass` statement at the end of a method? Why do `isinstance(cls.instance, type(None))` instead of `cls.instance is None`?

Comment: @Heidll yes, as I had explained, that's because `__bases__` is a *descriptor*, it belongs to the *class of the class*, i.e. the metaclass, i.e. `type` in this case.

Comment: Okey, thanks you all, now i have a little bit more understanding of oop in python :)