# Subclassing: Is it possible to override a property with a conventional attribute?

Tags: python, inheritance, properties

Let's assume we want to create a family of classes which are different implementations or specializations of an overarching concept. Let's assume there is a plausible default implementation for some derived properties. We'd want to put this into a base class

```
class Math_Set_Base:
    @property
    def size(self):
        return len(self.elements)
```

So a subclass will automatically be able to count its elements in this rather silly example

```
class Concrete_Math_Set(Math_Set_Base):
    def __init__(self,*elements):
        self.elements = elements

Concrete_Math_Set(1,2,3).size
# 3
```

But what if a subclass doesn't want to use this default? This does not work:

```
import math

class Square_Integers_Below(Math_Set_Base):
    def __init__(self,cap):
        self.size = int(math.sqrt(cap))

Square_Integers_Below(7)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
# AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I realize there are ways to override a property with a property, but I'd like to avoid that. Because the purpose of the base class is to make life as easy as possible for its user, not to add bloat by imposing a (from the subclass's narrow point of view) convoluted and superfluous access method.

Can it be done? If not what's the next best solution?

Comment: This likely indicates a problem with the class hierarchy itself. The best solution then is to rework that hierarchy. You mention that *"there is a plausible default implementation for some derived properties"* with the example of math sets and `len(self.elements)` as an implementation. This very specific implementation imposes a contract on all instances of the class, namely that they provide `elements` which is a *sized container*. However your `Square_Integers_Below` class doesn't seem to behave that way (perhaps it's generating its members dynamically), so it must define its own behavior.

Comment: Overriding is only necessary because it inherited the (wrong) behavior in the first place. `len(self.elements)` is not a suitable default implementation for math sets since there exist "many" sets that don't even have finite cardinality. In general, if a subclass doesn't want to use the behavior from its base classes, it needs to override it at the class level. Instance attributes, as the name suggests, work at the instance level and are hence governed by class behavior.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A property is a data descriptor which takes precedence over an instance attribute with the same name. You could define a non-data descriptor with a unique `__get__()` method: an instance attribute takes precedence over the **non-data descriptor** with the same name, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol). The problem here is that the `non_data_property` defined below is for computation purpose only (you can't define a setter or a deleter) but it seems to be the case in your example.

```py
import math

class non_data_property:
    def __init__(self, fget):
        self.__doc__ = fget.__doc__
        self.fget = fget

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return self.fget(obj)

class Math_Set_Base:
    @non_data_property
    def size(self, *elements):
        return len(self.elements)

class Concrete_Math_Set(Math_Set_Base):
    def __init__(self, *elements):
        self.elements = elements


class Square_Integers_Below(Math_Set_Base):
    def __init__(self, cap):
        self.size = int(math.sqrt(cap))

print(Concrete_Math_Set(1, 2, 3).size) # 3
print(Square_Integers_Below(1).size) # 1
print(Square_Integers_Below(4).size) # 2
print(Square_Integers_Below(9).size) # 3
```

However this assumes that you have access to the base class in order to make this changes.

Comment: This s pretty close to perfect. So this means a poperty even if you only define the getter does implicitly add a setter that does nothing apart from blocking assignment? Interesting. I'll probably accept this answer.

Comment: Yes, according to the docs, a property always defines all three descriptor methods (`__get__()`, `__set__()` and `__delete__()`) and they raise an `AttributeError` if you do not provide any function for them. See [Python equivalent of property implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties).

Comment: As long as you don't care for the `setter` or `__set__` of the property, this will work.  However I would caution you that this also means you can easily overwrite the property not just at class level (`self.size = ...`) but even in instance level (e.g. `Concrete_Math_Set(1, 2, 3).size = 10` would be equally valid).  Food for thoughts :)

Comment: And  `Square_Integers_Below(9).size = 1` is also valid as it is a simple attribute. In this particular "size" use case, this may seem akward (use a property instead), but in the general case "override a computed prop easily in subclass", it might be good in some cases. You can also control attribute access with `__setattr__()` but it could be overwhelming.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing there might be valid use case for these, I just wanted to mention the caveat as it can complicate debugging efforts in the future.  As long as both you and OP are aware of the implications then all is fine.

Answer (score 14):

This will be a long winded answer that might only serve to be complimentary... but your question took me for a ride down the rabbit hole so I'd like to share my findings (and pain) as well.

You might ultimately find this answer not helpful to your actual problem.  In fact, my conclusion is that - I wouldn't do this at all.  Having said that, the background to this conclusion might entertain you a bit, since you're looking for more details.

---

### Addressing some misconception

The first answer, while correct in most cases, is not *always* the case.  For instance, consider this class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Foo!'
        @property
        def inst_prop():
            return f'Retrieving {self.name}'
        self.inst_prop = inst_prop
```

`inst_prop`, while being a `property`, is irrevocably an instance attribute:

```
>>> Foo.inst_prop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#60>", line 1, in <module>
    Foo.inst_prop
AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'inst_prop'
>>> Foo().inst_prop
<property object at 0x032B93F0>
>>> Foo().inst_prop.fget()
'Retrieving Foo!'
```

It all depends *where* your `property` is defined in the first place.  If your `@property` is defined within the class "scope" (or really, the [`namespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax)), it becomes a class attribute.  In my example, the class itself isn't aware of any `inst_prop` until instantiated.  Of course, it's not very useful as a property at all here.

---

### But first, let's address your comment on inheritance resolution...

So how exactly does inheritance factor into this issue? This following article dives a little bit into the topic, and the [Method Resolution Order](https://blog.usejournal.com/playing-with-inheritance-in-python-73ea4f3b669e#ed6d) is somewhat related, though it discusses mostly the Breadth of inheritance instead of Depth.

Combined with our finding, given these below setup:

```
@property
def some_prop(self):
    return "Family property"

class Grandparent:
    culture = some_prop
    world_view = some_prop

class Parent(Grandparent):
    world_view = "Parent's new world_view"

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.world_view = "Child's new world_view"
            self.culture = "Child's new culture"
        except AttributeError as exc:
            print(exc)
            self.__dict__['culture'] = "Child's desired new culture"
```

Imagine what happens when these lines are executed:

```
print("Instantiating Child class...")
c = Child()
print(f'c.__dict__ is: {c.__dict__}')
print(f'Child.__dict__ is: {Child.__dict__}')
print(f'c.world_view is: {c.world_view}')
print(f'Child.world_view is: {Child.world_view}')
print(f'c.culture is: {c.culture}')
print(f'Child.culture is: {Child.culture}')
```

The result is thus:

> ```
> Instantiating Child class...
> can't set attribute
> c.__dict__ is: {'world_view': "Child's new world_view", 'culture': "Child's desired new culture"}
> Child.__dict__ is: {'__module__': '__main__', '__init__': <function Child.__init__ at 0x0068ECD8>, '__doc__': None}
> c.world_view is: Child's new world_view
> Child.world_view is: Parent's new world_view
> c.culture is: Family property
> Child.culture is: <property object at 0x00694C00>
> ```

Notice how:

1. `self.world_view` was able to be applied, while `self.culture` failed
2. `culture` does not exist in `Child.__dict__` (the [`mappingproxy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720492/why-is-a-class-dict-a-mappingproxy) of the class, not to be confused with the instance `__dict__`)
3. Even though `culture` exists in `c.__dict__`, it is not referenced.

You might be able to guess why - `world_view` was overwritten by `Parent` class as a non-property, so `Child` was able to overwrite it as well.  Meanwhile, since `culture` is inherited, *it only exists within the `mappingproxy` of `Grandparent`*:

```
Grandparent.__dict__ is: {
    '__module__': '__main__', 
    'culture': <property object at 0x00694C00>, 
    'world_view': <property object at 0x00694C00>, 
    ...
}
```

In fact if you try to remove `Parent.culture`:

> ```
> >>> del Parent.culture
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#67>", line 1, in <module>
>     del Parent.culture
> AttributeError: culture
> ```

You will notice it doesn't even exist for `Parent`.  Because the object is directly referring back to `Grandparent.culture`.

---

### So, what about the Resolution Order?

So we are interested to observe the actual Resolution Order, let's try removing `Parent.world_view` instead:

```
del Parent.world_view
print(f'c.world_view is: {c.world_view}')
print(f'Child.world_view is: {Child.world_view}')
```

Wonder what the result is?

> ```
> c.world_view is: Family property
> Child.world_view is: <property object at 0x00694C00>
> ```

It reverted back to Grandparent's `world_view` `property`, even though we had successfully manage to assign the `self.world_view` before! But what if we forcefully change `world_view` at the class level, like the other answer? What if we delete it? What if we assign the current class attribute to be a property?

```
Child.world_view = "Child's independent world_view"
print(f'c.world_view is: {c.world_view}')
print(f'Child.world_view is: {Child.world_view}')

del c.world_view
print(f'c.world_view is: {c.world_view}')
print(f'Child.world_view is: {Child.world_view}')

Child.world_view = property(lambda self: "Child's own property")
print(f'c.world_view is: {c.world_view}')
print(f'Child.world_view is: {Child.world_view}')
```

The result is:

> ```
> # Creating Child's own world view
> c.world_view is: Child's new world_view
> Child.world_view is: Child's independent world_view
>
> # Deleting Child instance's world view
> c.world_view is: Child's independent world_view
> Child.world_view is: Child's independent world_view
>
> # Changing Child's world view to the property
> c.world_view is: Child's own property
> Child.world_view is: <property object at 0x020071B0>
> ```

This is interesting because `c.world_view` is restored to its instance attribute, while `Child.world_view` is the one we assigned.  After removing the instance attribute, it reverts to the class attribute.  And after reassigning the `Child.world_view` to the property, we instantly lose access to the instance attribute.

**Therefore, we can surmise the following resolution order**:

1. If a class attribute exists **and** it is a `property`, retrieve its value via `getter` or `fget` (more on this later).  Current class first to Base class last.
2. Otherwise, if an instance attribute exist, retrieve the instance attribute value.
3. Else, retrieve the non-`property` class attribute.  Current class first to Base class last.

In that case, let's remove the root `property`:

```
del Grandparent.culture
print(f'c.culture is: {c.culture}')
print(f'Child.culture is: {Child.culture}')
```

Which gives:

> ```
> c.culture is: Child's desired new culture
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#74>", line 1, in <module>
>     print(f'Child.culture is: {Child.culture}')
> AttributeError: type object 'Child' has no attribute 'culture'
> ```

**Ta-dah!** `Child` now has their own `culture` based on the forceful insertion into `c.__dict__`.  `Child.culture` doesn't exist, of course, since it was never defined in `Parent` or `Child` class attribute, and `Grandparent`'s was removed.

---

### Is this the root cause of my problem?

Actually, **no**.  The error you're getting, which we're still observing when assigning `self.culture`, is *totally different*.  But the inheritance order sets the backdrop to the answer - which is the `property` itself.

Besides the previously mentioned `getter` method, [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) also have a few neat tricks up its sleeves.  The most relevant in this case is the `setter`, or `fset` method, which is triggered by `self.culture = ...` line.  Since your `property` didn't implement any `setter` or `fget` function, python doesn't know what to do, and throws an `AttributeError` instead (i.e. `can't set attribute`).

If however you implemented a `setter` method:

```
@property
def some_prop(self):
    return "Family property"

@some_prop.setter
def some_prop(self, val):
    print(f"property setter is called!")
    # do something else...
```

When instantiating the `Child` class you will get:

> ```
> Instantiating Child class...
> property setter is called!
> ```

Instead of receiving an `AttributeError`, you are now actually calling the `some_prop.setter` method.  Which gives you more control over your object... with our previous findings, we know that we need to have a class attribute overwritten *before* it reaches the property.  This could be implemented within the base class as a trigger.  Here's a fresh example:

```
class Grandparent:
    @property
    def culture(self):
        return "Family property"
    
    # add a setter method
    @culture.setter
    def culture(self, val):
        print('Fine, have your own culture')
        # overwrite the child class attribute
        type(self).culture = None
        self.culture = val

class Parent(Grandparent):
    pass

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.culture = "I'm a millennial!"

c = Child()
print(c.culture)
```

Which results in:

> ```
> Fine, have your own culture
> I'm a millennial!
> ```

**TA-DAH!** You can now overwrite your own instance attribute over an inherited property!

---

### So, problem solved?

... Not really.  The problem with this approach is, now you can't have a proper `setter` method.  There are cases where you do want to set values on your `property`.  But now whenever you set `self.culture = ...` it will *always* overwrite whatever function you defined in the `getter` (which in this instance, really is just the `@property` wrapped portion.  You *can* add in more nuanced measures, but one way or another it'll always involve more than just `self.culture = ...`.  e.g.:

```
class Grandparent:
    # ...
    @culture.setter
    def culture(self, val):
        if isinstance(val, tuple):
            if val[1]:
                print('Fine, have your own culture')
                type(self).culture = None
                self.culture = val[0]
        else:
            raise AttributeError("Oh no you don't")

# ...

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            # Usual setter
            self.culture = "I'm a Gen X!"
        except AttributeError:
            # Trigger the overwrite condition
            self.culture = "I'm a Boomer!", True
```

It's *waaaaay* more complicated than the other answer, `size = None` at the class level.

You could also consider writing your own [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) instead to handle the `__get__` and `__set__`, or additional methods.  But at the end of the day, when `self.culture` is referenced, the `__get__` will always be triggered first, and when `self.culture = ...` is referenced, `__set__` will always be triggered first.  There's no getting around it as far as I've tried.

---

### The crux of the issue, IMO

The problem I see here is - you can't have your cake and eat it too.  `property` is meant like a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) with convenient access from methods like `getattr` or `setattr`.  If you also want these methods to achieve a different purpose, you're just asking for trouble.  I would perhaps rethink the approach:

1. Do I really need a `property` for this?
2. Could a method serve me any differently?
3. If I need a `property`, is there any reason I would need to overwrite it?
4. Does the subclass really belong in the same family if these `property` don't apply?
5. If I do need to overwrite any/all `property`s, would a separate method serve me better than simply reassigning, since reassigning can accidentally void the `property`s?

For point 5, my approach would be have an `overwrite_prop()` method in the base class that overwrite the current class attribute so that the `property` will no longer be triggered:

```
class Grandparent:
    # ...
    def overwrite_props(self):
        # reassign class attributes
        type(self).size = None
        type(self).len = None
        # other properties, if necessary

# ...

# Usage
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.overwrite_props()
        self.size = 5
        self.len = 10
```

As you can see, while still a bit contrived, it is at least more explicit than a cryptic `size = None`.  That said, ultimately, I wouldn't overwrite the property at all, and would reconsider my design from the root.

If you have made it this far - thank you for walking this journey with me.  It was a fun little exercise.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! It will take me a bit of time to digest this, but I suppose I asked for it.

Answer (score 9):

A `@property` is defined at the class level. [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) goes into exhaustive detail on how it works, but suffice it to say that *setting* or *getting* the property resolve into calling a particular method. However, the `property` object that manages this process is defined with the class's own definition. That is, it's defined as a class variable but behaves like an instance variable.

One consequence of this is that you can reassign it freely *at the class level*:

```
print(Math_Set_Base.size)
# <property object at 0x10776d6d0>

Math_Set_Base.size = 4
print(Math_Set_Base.size)
# 4
```

And just like any other class-level name (e.g. methods), you can override it in a subclass by just explicitly defining it differently:

```
class Square_Integers_Below(Math_Set_Base):
    # explicitly define size at the class level to be literally anything other than a @property
    size = None

    def __init__(self,cap):
        self.size = int(math.sqrt(cap))

print(Square_Integers_Below(4).size)  # 2
print(Square_Integers_Below.size)     # None
```

When we create an actual instance, the instance variable simply shadows the class variable of the same name. The `property` object normally uses some shenanigans to manipulate this process (i.e. applying getters and setters) but when the class-level name isn't defined as a property, nothing special happens, and so it acts as you'd expect of any other variable.

Comment: Thanks, that's refreshingly simple. Does it mean that even if there never were any properties anywhere in my class and its ancestors it still will first search through the entire inheritance tree for a class level name before it even bothers looking at the `__dict__`? Also, are there any ways to automate this? Yes, it's just one line but it's the kind of thing that is very cryptic to read if you are not familiar with the gory details of proprties etc.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I haven't looked into the procedures behind this, so I couldn't give you a satisfactory answer myself. You can try to puzzle it out from [the cpython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython) if you want. As for automating the process, I don't think there's a good way to do that other than either not making it a property in the first place, or just adding a comment/docstring to let those reading your code know what you're doing. Something like `# declare size to not be a @property`

Answer (score 7):

You don't need assignment (to `size`) at all. `size` is a property in the base class, so you can override that property in the child class:

```
class Math_Set_Base:
    @property
    def size(self):
        return len(self.elements)

    # size = property(lambda self: self.elements)


class Square_Integers_Below(Math_Set_Base):

    def __init__(self, cap):
        self._cap = cap

    @property
    def size(self):
        return int(math.sqrt(self._cap))

    # size = property(lambda self: int(math.sqrt(self._cap)))
```

You can (micro)optimize this by precomputing the square root:

```
class Square_Integers_Below(Math_Set_Base):

    def __init__(self, cap):
        self._size = int(math.sqrt(self._cap))

    @property
    def size(self):
        return self._size
```

Comment: That's a great point, just override a parent property with a child property! +1

Comment: This is in a way the straight-forward thing to do, but I was interested in and did ask specifically for ways tio allow a non property override so as not to impose the inconvenience of having to write a memoizing property where simple assignment would do the job.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to complicate your code like that. For the small price of recognizing that `size` is a property and not an instance attribute, you don't have to do *anything* fancy.

Comment: My use case is lots of child classes with lots of attributes; not having to write 5 lines instead of one for all those justifies a certain amount of fancicity, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to define `size` in your class:

```
class Square_Integers_Below(Math_Set_Base):
    size = None

    def __init__(self, cap):
        self.size = int(math.sqrt(cap))
```

Another option is to store `cap` in your class and calculate it with `size` defined as a property (which overrides the base class's property `size`).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest adding a setter like so:

```
class Math_Set_Base:
    @property
    def size(self):
        try:
            return self._size
        except:
            return len(self.elements)

    @size.setter
    def size(self, value):
        self._size = value
```

This way you can override the default `.size` property like so:

```
class Concrete_Math_Set(Math_Set_Base):
    def __init__(self,*elements):
        self.elements = elements

class Square_Integers_Below(Math_Set_Base):
    def __init__(self,cap):
        self.size = int(math.sqrt(cap))

print(Concrete_Math_Set(1,2,3).size) # 3
print(Square_Integers_Below(7).size) # 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do next thing

```
class Math_Set_Base:
    _size = None

    def _size_call(self):
       return len(self.elements)

    @property
    def size(self):
        return  self._size if self._size is not None else self._size_call()

class Concrete_Math_Set(Math_Set_Base):
    def __init__(self, *elements):
        self.elements = elements


class Square_Integers_Below(Math_Set_Base):
    def __init__(self, cap):
        self._size = int(math.sqrt(cap))
```

Comment: That's neat, but you don't really need `_size` or `_size_call` there.  You could have baked in the function call within `size` as a condition, and use `try... except... ` to test for `_size` instead of taking an extra class reference that won't get used.  Regardless though, I feel this is even more cryptic than the simple `size = None` overwriting in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible to set a property of a base class to another property from a derived class, inside the derived class and then to use the property of the base class with a new value.

In the initial code there is a sort of conflict between the name `size` from the base class and the attribute `self.size` from the derived class. This can be visible if we replace the name `self.size` from the derived class with `self.length`. This will output:

```
3
<__main__.Square_Integers_Below object at 0x000001BCD56B6080>
```

Then, if we replace the name of the method `size` with `length` in all occurrences throughout the program, this will result in the same exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Maria/Downloads/so_1.2.py", line 24, in <module>
    Square_Integers_Below(7)
  File "C:/Users/Maria/Downloads/so_1.2.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.length = int(math.sqrt(cap))
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

The fixed code, or anyway, a version that somehow works, is to keep the code exactly the same, with the exception of the class `Square_Integers_Below`, which will set the method `size` from the base class, to another value.

```
class Square_Integers_Below(Math_Set_Base):

    def __init__(self,cap):
        #Math_Set_Base.__init__(self)
        self.length = int(math.sqrt(cap))
        Math_Set_Base.size = self.length

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.size)
```

And then, when we run all of the program, the output is:

```
3
2
```

I hope this was helpful in one way or another.