# How to deal with mappingproxy when working with class methods?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, class-method

I've recently been experimenting with the use of class methods to get a better understanding of object-oriented programming. As part of a sample program I've got a short class called `circle`, which can be used to create different `circle` instances.

```
class circle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.radius = 10
        self.color = 'blue'
    def change_color(self, color):
        self.color = color

    @classmethod
    def red_circle(cls):
        circle.radius = 10
        circle.color = 'red'
        return cls
```

I've added in the class method `red_circle` so that I can have a different default setting for `circle` instances. The problem I have is that when I use the `red_circle` method, the instance created is placed inside of `mappingproxy()`? For example:

```
circle_one = circle()
circle_one.__dict__
```

Gives the output:

```
{'radius': 10, 'color': 'blue'}
```

But using

```
circle_two = circle.red_circle()
circle_two.__dict__
```

Gives:

```
mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'circle' objects>,
              '__doc__': None,
              '__init__': <function __main__.circle.__init__>,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'circle' objects>,
              'change_color': <function __main__.circle.change_color>,
              'color': 'orange',
              'radius': 10,
              'red_circle': <classmethod at 0x7f0e94ab1a10>})
```

Is there a way that I can manipulate `circle_two` so that it appears the same as the `circle_one` instance? It's not causing any problems right now, but it would be good to understand what's going on with the `mappingproxy()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble with your existing code is that your `red_circle` method, as it stands, is attempting to alter *attributes of the `circle` class* rather than *attributes of any one instance of the `circle` class*.

You can fix this by rewriting it like so:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.radius = 10
        self.color = 'blue'

    def change_color(self, color):
        self.color = color

    @classmethod
    def red_circle(cls):
        new_circle = cls()
        new_circle.change_color('red')
        return new_circle
```

A few points to note here:

- I've renamed your `circle` class to `Circle`. It's a strong convention in python code to capitalise names of classes, and you're likely to confuse other programmers if you don't do that.
- Unlike with functions, you don't need brackets when declaring a class, unless you're inheriting from another class.
- Just as an instance method always takes the *instance of the class* as its first parameter (and there's a strong convention to always call that parameter `self`), a class method will always take *the class itself* as its first parameter (and there's a strong convention to always call that parameter `cls`).

**`mappingproxy` objects**

`mappingproxy` objects are (to simplify a little here) immutable dictionaries. While ordinary dictionaries are used for instance dictionaries, `mappingproxy` objects are used for class dictionaries. There's a good explanation of why a different kind of dictionary is used for the class dict here: [Why is a class __dict__ a mappingproxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720492/why-is-a-class-dict-a-mappingproxy).

**Class dicts vs instance dicts**

In your `circle` class, the `radius` and `color` attributes are *instance* attributes. Each instance of `circle` has its own version of them, and keeps those versions in its own personalised instance dictionary. However, the methods in your `circle` class — `__init__`, `change_color` and `red_circle` — are *class* attributes. These methods are kept in the class dictionary — the `mappingproxy` object you came across. All instances of `circle` have access to the same class dictionary, and this is how they access these methods.

You can find a good introductory tutorial on the different kinds of python methods [here](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/).

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for such a detailed answer! This kind of answer is exactly what I was hoping for. The article you linked at the end is the article I've actually been using to wrap my head around the issue so far haha, I agree that it is a really good introductory tutorial though

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!