# Is it possible to make etree._Element printable?

Tags: python, elementtree

When using lxml I often want more information about an element. When using `print (element)` one does not get much information. Is it possible to change this? It would be nice if I could write a custom function that displays more information, e.g. the element's text. I already tried `setattr`, but this does not work. The reason for this is explained [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019333/how-to-modify-class-dict-a-mappingproxy?noredirect=1&lq=1)

An example:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring("<html>this is a test</html>")

print (root)
```

The is results in: `<Element html at 0x7f582daeb700>`

**Update:** Ideally, I would want to be able to just write `print (element)` and get a nicely formatted output. I was hoping that I could achieve this using a [custom `__str__`](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-str-method-in-python) method somehow.

Comment: Did you try `etree.tostring()`, perhaps with a `pretty_print = True` parameter?

Comment: My aim is to achieve this using just print(element), e.g. by adding a __str__ method. In the method I could then add etree.tostring() indeed. (Updated the question accordingly to make this clearer)

Comment: You _may_ subclass `etree`, of course, but tbh that seems to me far more complicated than just using `print(element.tostring())`

Comment: Subclassing probably would not help, as the etree functions would still return "normal" etree-Elements. I guess what I am looking for is simply not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element text by `print(root.text)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My hope is to just use print(element) without an external function, so this will not work for me. I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without any external library. Just like the below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring("<html>this is a test</html>")
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<html>this is a test</html>
```